# "ill" in present continuous

Tags: present-progressive, present-continuous

Present continuous tense Rules. Auxiliary verb “am or is or are” is used in sentence. 1st form of verb or base verb + ing (presentparticiple) is used as main verb in sentence.
Question: Can we form the with verb **ill**?
For example:
I am illing or I am ill. What is the right and why?

Comment: Pajsije, what is your motivation, that is, what did you think or hear that prompted you to ask this question? 'Ill' can be used as a verb but it is old-fashioned (1970s/80s) AAVE slang, meaning 'being crazy'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ill is not a verb.
If you asked me, I'm not sure if there is the verb that meaning would be "to get sick" or "to get ill".

Comment: [You be illin'](https://www.google.com/search?q=you+be+illin+lyrics)

Comment: I found that "ill" is adjective in english, ill, iller, illest. That is why we can't add "ing".

Comment: @Pajsije As a verb, ["illin'" is slang](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=illin%27) (mostly AAVE) for 'acting strange' or 'messing around' by extension from the adjective meaning 'to be sick'. It's a bit slippery so can be applied to a number of slightly different situations. It was around way before RunDMC used it in the early 80's in the US.

Comment: Thank you Mitch. Verry useful.